# How to prevent method recalled again when redirect back Angular

Tags: angular

Lets say that i clicked the Tracked Order button , it will direct to the Track Order Page. But when I redirect back to the My Order Page, it recalled the same method causing it display twice like the image below. Suppose it only has 1 orders. Is there a way to prevent this?

[image: ngular]

This is my my order page typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.page.scss'],
})
export class OrdersPage implements OnInit {
  orders=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public share: ShareService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.orders=this.share.getOrders();
  }

}
```

This is my share service typescript

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareService{
    url:string="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder";
    orders= [];
    constructor(private http:Http){

    }
    public getAll()
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(res=>res.json());
    }

    public getOrders(){

        this.getAll().subscribe(data =>{
          for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
          {
            this.orders.push(data[i]);
          }
        })
        return this.orders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being inside the service, the *orders* array keeps its value upon navigation.
As you push data on each Component intialization, this array keeps growing.
If this array is only meant to be used by your component, your should just delete it and let `getOrders()` return the value emitted by the observable (you can even remove the loop as at the end it just duplicate it)

You can simplify your workflow using the **async** pipe to clean your code and get automatic unsubscription on your observable :

Component :

```
orders$: Observable<Orders>;

constructor(private share: ShareService) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.orders$ = this.share.getAll(); // you don't need getOrders() anymore
}
```

Template :

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders$ | async"> // the pipe has a built-in subscription
<!-- order template -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `this.orders` in the service is already assigned a value when you redirect back to the page. You need to return the observable from the service and subscribe to in the controller. That way the `orders` array in the controller is assigned a new value everytime the component is loaded.

Besides, if you aren't modifying the data from the backend, the `for` isn't required. You could directly assign the response to the `orders` array. Try the following

Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class ShareService{
  url:string="https://localhost:44399/api/APIOrder";
  orders= [];

  constructor(private http:Http){ }

  public getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

Controller

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.page.scss'],
})
export class OrdersPage implements OnInit {
  orders=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public share: ShareService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.share.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.orders = data;
    });
  }
}
```